# UIScrollView, Pull down effect similar to CalcBot

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, uiscrollview

I'm trying to make a UI similar to CalcBot where you can pull down the view controller with your finger and it reveals a hidden background view.

I think this is done with the UIScrollView but cannot work out the exact method to have for example 2x Horizontal views with one of them having a vertical.

[image: Example of what I am trying to achieve]

I do have the horizontal scroll working fine, i'm just stuck with how I can make screen 1 pull down with a vertical scroller.

Any tips or pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks Aaron

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have nested scrollviews to get scrolling working in both directions. Let's have a vertical scroller inside a horizontal scroller (though you can very well do it the other way round too), so views 3 and 1 get into a vertical scrollview, which in turn gets inside a horizontal scroller along with view 2.

You could create such a view hierarchy in code (probably in the main viewcontroller's `viewDidLoad`). The following snippet assumes view1, view2 and view3 as webviews.

```
CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;

// main guy is a horizontal scroller
UIScrollView *hScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
hScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(bounds.size.width * 2, bounds.size.height);
hScrollView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:hScrollView];

// the horizontal scroller contains a vertical scroller
UIScrollView *vScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
vScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height * 2);
vScrollView.delegate = self;
[hScrollView addSubview:vScrollView];

// add view3 and view1 to the vertical scroller
UIWebView *view3 = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
[view3 loadHTMLString:@"<h1>3</h1>" baseURL:nil];
[vScrollView addSubview:view3];

UIWebView *view1 = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(bounds, 0, bounds.size.height)];
[view1 loadHTMLString:@"<h1>1</h1>" baseURL:nil];
[vScrollView addSubview:view1];
vScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, bounds.size.height);

// add view2 to the horizontal scroller
UIWebView *view2 = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(bounds, bounds.size.width, 0)];
[view2 loadHTMLString:@"<h1>2</h1>" baseURL:nil];    
[hScrollView addSubview:view2];

// enable paging in both directions
hScrollView.pagingEnabled = TRUE;
vScrollView.pagingEnabled = TRUE;
```

That would have you scrolling in both directions but that would also let you scroll-right from view3 to view2. If you want to prevent that, you should disable scrolling on `hScrollView` whenever the `vScollView` is showing view3. You can do that in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` in the delegate of `vScrollView`. Something like:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == self.verticalScrollView) {
        self.horizontalScrollView.scrollEnabled = (self.verticalScrollView.contentOffset.y > self.view.bounds.origin.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help this code is perfect for my needs and works really well. I just have one slight problem now when I am in vScrollView from 1 - 3. When I am on Screen 3 I can swipe right to screen 2 which is not what I want to happen. Thanks Aaron

Comment: As I indicated in the original answer, you can prevent scrolling right from view3 to view2 by implementing `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`. Have added some code to illustrate.